# I want to convert col-sm-4 to two equal column and one row at bottom in twitter bootsrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hai I have created three column in one row col-sm-4,col-sm-4,col-sm-4 and every column must be splitt with two equal column and one row at the footer.Like below image,

[This is the sample alignment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7f4C.png)

and my code is ,

```html
 <div class="container">    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">
           
              
            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
          
          </div>
        </div>
          
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;" >
            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_5.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

please give the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use following HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the following structure..As according to bootstrap docs all the new row should be wrapped within `<div class="row"></div>`.

So your `class="col-sm-12"` which is **one row at the footer** according to your question should also be wrapped within a new `class="row"`.

All the above answer will work as they will create a new row but they are not following the bootstrap grid system properly.

```css
.col-sm-6 {
            background-color: red;
            height: 200px;
          }
          .col-sm-12 {
            background-color: yellow;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #col2 {
            background-color: blue;
            height: 200px;
          }
 .row {
          border: 5px solid black;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

       
           </head>
<body >
 <div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div id="col2" class="col-sm-6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div id="col2" class="col-sm-6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                <div id="col2" class="col-sm-6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code format

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">


            <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for your image structure,

[image]

Check this code in full-screen view only then you can see the structure, in small screen due to responsiveness structure will change.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">     
      <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
       </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;" alt="Image"></div>     
         
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">            
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">     
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       

      <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">     
      <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
       </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>     
         
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">            
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">     
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">     
      <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
       </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>     
         
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">            
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">     
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">     
      <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
       </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>     
         
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">            
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">     
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       

      <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">     
      <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
       </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>     
         
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">            
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">     
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="panel panel-primary" onclick="location.href='game.aspx?id=2'" style="cursor: pointer;">     
      <div class="panel-heading">BLACK FRIDAY DEAL</div>
       </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>     
         
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">            
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/150x80_4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">     
            <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card</div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```